# Error:new bignumber() not a base 16 number

Tags: web3js

I have built a private chain with two node on two computer. The smart contract was successfully deployed on node1,and i can call the method on node1 ,but when i call the same method on node2,it occur the error new BigNumber not a base 16 number
[image: the error on node2]

[image: the return on node1]

BTW,the two node have the same block number!

Comment: the first pic is the error on node2,and the second pic is the return on node1

Comment: check if they are synched

Comment: if the two nodes have the same block number means they are synched? I check the block number on two nodes by using the command eth.getBlock("latest").number  and both of them return 953.

Comment: check using .toNumber()

Comment: Do you mean the eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase).toNumber()  function?? I executed this command above on the two nodes and get the same result .

Comment: var v=contract.getOw...
v.toNumbr()

Comment: so frustrating that it didn't work, and raise the same error when i execute the command var v = contract.getOwerName(2)

Comment: what about var v = contract.getOwerName(2).toNumber();

Comment: It also got the same error

Comment: i think the nodes aren't synched try to execute eth.getCode("contract addres") in the faulty node

Comment: It return a long string "0x606060405260043610610099576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063025e7c271461009e5780630cc9c17b1461013a5780632201bb661461021e5780638230c4fb14610293578063893d20e81461032f5780638da5cb5b14610384578063be6851a5146103d9578063d924100e14610508578063f2fde38b14610531575b600080fd5b34156100a957600080fd5b6100bf600480803590602001909190505061056a56.........."

Comment: check your contract2 variable maybe your ABI or address are wrong

Comment: yes ,i have check the abi and the address from char to char before post the question here and nothing wrong. And the abi and address are copy from the same file . I am trying to deploy another node on other computer to test if anything wrong!!